# integrate code in deezer app No view found for id 0x7f070000 for fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat

I'm working on an application in the context of a class project, the application is based on the api Deezer, I worked a code navigation drawer with swype tabs. 
when I integrated the code with the code deezer, the application gives the error Unfortunately stopped. and the error in the logcat is "No view found for id 0x7f05003f (com.ift2905project.tunemyday: id / content_frame) for fragment FragmentProfile {b1289920 # id = 0} 0x7f05003f"

```
package com.ift2905project.tunemyday;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnect;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerConnectImpl;
import com.deezer.sdk.DeezerError;
import com.deezer.sdk.DialogError;
import com.deezer.sdk.DialogListener;
import com.deezer.sdk.OAuthException;
import com.deezer.sdk.SessionStore;



public abstract class BaseActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private static final String LOG_TAG = "BaseActivity";   

    private static final int MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT = 0;

    public static final String APP_ID = "135053";

    protected static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[] {"basic_access","offline_access", "email", "manage_library"};
    protected DeezerConnect deezerConnect = null; 

    DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    ListView mDrawerList;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    String[] title;
    String[] subtitle;
    int[] icon;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;
    MenuListAdapter mMenuAdapter;

    Fragment profile = new FragmentProfile();
    Fragment top = new FragmentTop();
    Fragment playlists = new FragmentPlaylists(); 
    Fragment favoris = new FragmentFavoris(); 
    Fragment suggestion = new FragmentSuggestions();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        deezerConnect = new DeezerConnectImpl( this, APP_ID );
        setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        title = new String[] { "Profile", "Top", "Playlists", "Favoris", "Suggestions" };

        subtitle = new String[] { "Profile", "Top", "Playlists", "Favoris", "Suggestions" };

        icon = new int[] { R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher, R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher };

mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow,
                GravityCompat.START);

        mMenuAdapter = new MenuListAdapter(BaseActivity.this, title, subtitle,
                icon);

        mDrawerList.setAdapter(mMenuAdapter);

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close) {

            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            selectItem(0);
        }
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected1(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            if (mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList)) {
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            } else {
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mDrawerList);
            }
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements
    ListView.OnItemClickListener {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {
    selectItem(position);
}
}
    private void selectItem(int position) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, profile );
            break;
        case 1:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, top);
            break;
        case 2:
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, playlists);
            break; 
        case 3: 
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, favoris);
            break ; 
        case 4: 
            ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, suggestion);
            break;
        }
        ft.commit();
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(title[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    public void onConfigurationChanged1(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        if (manager.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
            manager.popBackStack();

        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem itemLogout = menu.add(0, MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT,0, R.string.logout );
        itemLogout.setIcon( android.R.drawable.ic_lock_idle_lock );

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }


    protected void chooseServiceMenuItemIcon(MenuItem item) {
        if( item.isChecked() ) {
            item.setIcon( android.R.drawable.checkbox_on_background );
        } else {
            item.setIcon( android.R.drawable.checkbox_off_background );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if( item.getItemId() == MENU_ITEM_LOGOUT ) {
            disConnectFromDeezer();
            Intent intent = new Intent( this, LoginActivity.class );
            startActivity(intent);
        } 
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void disConnectFromDeezer() {
        if( deezerConnect != null ) {
            deezerConnect.logout( this );
        }
        new SessionStore().clear( this );
    }

    protected void reconnectToDeezer() {
        deezerConnect.authorize( this, PERMISSIONS, new ReconnectDialogHandler() );
    }

    protected void handleError( Exception exception ) {
        Toast.makeText( this, getResources().getString( R.string.download_error ), Toast.LENGTH_LONG ); 
        Log.e( LOG_TAG, "Exception during a query to Deezer services. ", exception );
    }

    protected class ReconnectDialogHandler implements DialogListener {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(final Bundle values) {
            SessionStore sessionStore = new SessionStore();
            sessionStore.save( deezerConnect, BaseActivity.this );
            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.this, R.string.user_authentified, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDeezerError(final DeezerError deezerError) {
            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.this, R.string.deezer_error_during_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            Log.e( LOG_TAG, "DialogError error during login" , deezerError );
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(final DialogError dialogError) {
            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.this, R.string.deezer_error_during_login, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
            Log.e( LOG_TAG, "DialogError error during login", dialogError );
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.this, R.string.login_cancelled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onOAuthException(OAuthException oAuthException) {
            Toast.makeText( BaseActivity.this, R.string.invalid_credentials, Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        }
    }

}

____________________________________________________________________
```

drawe_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/dropdownListPreferredItemHeight"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/subtitle"
            style="?attr/spinnerDropDownItemStyle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: just one thing I'm a beginner.

Comment: `drawe_main.xml` is that a typo?

Comment: sorry I don't undrestand what you mean ? my eglish is bas, I don'T undrestand abbreviation ?

Comment: I mean here `setContentView(R.layout.drawer_main);` it is written `drawer_main`, but in question you posted layout with name `drawe_main.xml` (missing `r`).

Comment: no it's correect in the code, I did a fault just in the post